# Protocol class and passing information

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I have a view controller that creates ObjectA. ObjectA then creates ObjectB. ObjectB needs to get some values from the view controller (i need values that can change after creation of the objects).

I'm trying to figure out the best way to retrieve the values. My first thought was with protocols. I have only created protocols within an object so far:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol AnalysisTypeTableDelegate;

@interface AnalysisTypeTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <AnalysisTypeTableDelegate> delegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataSource;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL allowRefresh;

@end

@protocol AnalysisTypeTableDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)returnAnalysisType:(NSString *)type;

@end
```

how can i create protocol class (such as create new file, objective-c protocol)?

Then how do I link them together? ObjectA has a protocol, do i do something like:

```
// View controller and objectB both conform to myProtocol

// view controller creates objectA
myObjectA.delegate = self

// when objectA creates objectB
myObjectB.delegate = self.delegate
```

Or is there a better way to retrieve the values i need?

EDIT:

I think I'll need to do something like this:

objectA's protocol:

```
@protocol objectADelegate

-(NSDictionary)requestViewController;

@end
```

objectB's protocols:

```
@protocol objectBDelegate

-(NSDictionary *)requestObjectA;

-(void)updateList:(NSSarray *)list;

@end
```

in myObjectB

```
-(NSDictionary *)requestObjectA {
    NSDictionary *extents = [self.delegate requestObjectA];
}

-(void)serverCall {
    // make server call, get list
    ...
    // update myObjectA with new list
    [self.delegate updateList:newList];
```

in myObjectA

```
-(NSDictionary *)requestObjectA {
    return [self.delegate requestViewController];
}

-(void)updateList:(NSArray)list {
    // updates list
}
```

in view controller

```
-(NSDictionary *)requestViewController;
    return self.mapkit.exents;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're saying that this is called from your view controller:

```
myObjectA.delegate = self
```

And that you're calling the following line from object A:

```
myObjectB.delegate = self.delegate
```

Technically, you can do that, though I find that construct a little confusing. And it's even a little problematic, because you don't provide any mechanism for the view controller to say "ok, I don't want to be a `delegate` anymore", because it presumably only knows about `myObjectA`. You don't have any mechanism for the view controller to tell `myObjectB` that it doesn't want to be its `delegate` any more, because presumably the view controller doesn't even know of `B`'s existence.

---

#### Use Model-View-Controller pattern

The notion of `delegate` is one of "I want to tell my `delegate` something, or make some request of it". If your goal, on the other hand, is to share data amongst them, I'd be inclined to shift away from the delegate-protocol pattern, and to a [model-view-controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) (MVC) pattern, and we'll focus on the "model" portion:

- Create a `Model` class to holds the model data;
- Have the view controller instantiate a `Model` class object;
- Pass pointers to the `Model` object from one view controller or object to the next (or otherwise make this model object accessible to other classes, via, for example, a singleton pattern, an app delegate property, etc.);
- Make sure your `Model` class has properties associated with data being maintained (that way, other classes can use the accessor methods that `Model` will synthesize for you).

This is conceptually very similar to what you've outlined with your `delegate` pointers, but doesn't carry the implications that `delegate` does, namely that you're not only accessing data, but rather you can tell the controller to do something. In a delegate-protocol pattern, the delegate should generally have the ability to opt out of being a `delegate` at any point.

---

#### Different approaches to handling changes in model data

There are several approaches for reflecting the change to a model object in other objects (e.g. to tell the view controller that model data has changed and it must reflect that change). These include:

1. Use delegates. This is probably the worst of the approaches that I'm listing here because if you want to tell multiple objects about the change in the model data, you have to have multiple delegates (or an array of them). This is a poor use of delegates.
2. Reload upon `viewDidAppear`. If you're only dealing with making sure that view controllers update their views to reflect data that changed on another view controller, you can just refresh the view when it appears again. This is the most primitive solution, and only works if you're dealing with view controllers that are reappearing after, for example, a modal view that altered the data has been dismissed. This is, in those simple cases, often the easiest solution.

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

       [self updateField1Label];
       [self updateField2Label];
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
   ```
3. [Register for notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver%3aselector%3aname%3aobject%3a) through the `NSNotificationCenter`. This has the beauty that multiple objects can add themselves as an observer to the same notification. For example, define a key for your notification in your .m file:

   ```
   NSString * const kNotificationField1Changed = @"com.log139.field1";
   ```

   Then, define an external reference to that key in your .h file:

   ```
   extern NSString * const kNotificationField1Changed;
   ```

   Then, the object that wants to be notified of the change can register for that notification:

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(handleField1Notification:)
                                                name:kNotificationField1Changed
                                              object:nil];
   ```

   Obviously, you have to write that "handler" method:

   ```
   - (void)handleField1Notification:(NSNotification*)notification
   {
       self.field1Label.text = self.model.name;
   }
   ```

   Finally, whatever updates that model field can post the notification, e.g.:

   ```
   - (void)saveAndPop:(UITextField *)textField
   {
       self.model.field1 = textField.text;

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationField1Changed
                                                           object:self
                                                         userInfo:nil];

       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
   ```

   If you do this, you just need to make sure that when the object that registered for the notification is going out of scope, it must also unregister for that notification:

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                   name:kNotificationField1Changed
                                                 object:nil];
   ```
4. Use [key value observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html). Again, multiple objects can register to be an observer of your model's properties. Let's assume that you have defined three properties (via `@property`) for your `Model` object. Any object that wants to be notified of changes can add themselves as an observer of those properties, e.g.:

   ```
   [self.model addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"field1" options:0 context:NULL];
   [self.model addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"field2" options:0 context:NULL];
   [self.model addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"field3" options:0 context:NULL];
   ```

   You then just need to write an [`observeValueForKeyPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observeValueForKeyPath%3aofObject%3achange%3acontext%3a) method:

   ```
   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
   {
       if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"field1"])
           [self updateField1Label];

       else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"field2"])
           [self updateField2Label];

       else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"field3"])
           [self.field3TableView reloadData];
   }
   ```

   The only thing that's tricky here is that if one of the objects is a collection (e.g. a `NSMutableArray`), you have to write [collection accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB). See that document for more examples. For example, though, I have a model that has a property that is an array of pet names, `NSMutableArray *petNames`. Thus, I had to write the following two methods for my model:

   ```
   - (void)insertObject:(NSString *)petName inPetNamesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
   {
       [self.petNames insertObject:petName atIndex:index];
   }

   - (void)removeObjectFromPetNamesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
   {
       [self.petNames removeObjectAtIndex:index];
   }
   ```

   And instead of ever calling `[self.model.petNames addObject:aPetName]`, I called `[self.model insertObject:aPetName inPetNamesAtIndex:0];` instead (and by doing that, the notifications take place automatically).

In short, if you have multiple objects that have to be notified of a change in your model data, I think that key-value-observing is the most elegant approach, but it takes a little time to get your arms around it if dealing with collections. I think that just posting notification is a relatively simple alternative.

---

#### References:

- [Model View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) in *Cocoa Core Competencies.*
- [Model View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14-SW1) in *Concepts in Objective-C Programming.*
- [Key Value Observing Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).
- [Key Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1)
- If you're dealing with collections with KVC, pay special attention to the [Collection Accessor Patterns for To-Many Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB) section of the *Key Value Coding Programming Guide.*

Comment: I want to be able to assign the view controller to myObjectB's delegate (so myObjectB can request information from the view controller). So I'm trying to create a connection from the view controller to myObjectB. My only thought is to pass a view controller's self through myObjectA and assign it in myObjectA.

Comment: @Log139 I've updated my answer with the typical pattern for this. It's not a delegate-protocol pattern, but rather a `Model` object pattern.

Comment: ok, i see what you are saying. myObjectB is a Model class object; it stores data and calls my server. One of the requirements it needs to call the server is the extents of a Mapkit in the view controller. myObectA is a submenu which the user interacts with to make the server requests. The only interaction i need between myObjectB and the view controller is requesting extents. I suppose i could create myObjectB in the view controller and pass myObjectB to myObjectA instead of myObjectA creating myObjectB.

Comment: k, i updated my question. I'm not sure what suggest is the best approach, but its the only way i see how to do it. myObjectB needs to talk to myObjectA (to tell it to update a list) and view controller (to get extents). my solution is the only way i can think of doing both (since there isn't away to have myObjectB to have two delegates that i know of other then createing two delegates; aka delegate1 and delegate2 which doesn't seem like an elegant solution).

Comment: @Log139 If you need to notify multiple objects about changes to your model, delegates is the wrong pattern. Better would be notifications or KVO (key value observing). See updated answer.

Comment: i thought about notification but didn't think that it was a good fit. Didn't think about KVO and i'll give that some thought. Thanks.

Comment: So I found a solution: I decided to create my model object in the main view controller. Then when i created ObjectA (or my sub menu), i pass the model object to it. So I keep a reference to the model object in the main view controller for when I need it. I then set the model's delegate to my sub menu. The sub menu's delegate is then set to the main view controller. Overall, I think this is a better way of handling events and changes. I very much appreciate your time and effort in helping, thank you.